# How to define types properly in error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I wrote simple function for error handling in typescript

```
async function exitOnError() {
const errors =  ['SIGTERM', 'SIGINT']
    errors.map((type) => {
        process.once(type, async () => {
            try {
                console.log(`Error process.on ${type}`);
                await service.disconnect;
            } finally {
                console.log(`Unexpected error happen on ${type}`);
                process.kill(process.pid, type);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I am getting following error when I use typescript.

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signals'.ts(2769)
process.d.ts(406, 17): The last overload is declared here.
(parameter) type: string
```

How can I fix it I tried if guards but still get error. As I understand it is `Signal` type. And how can I improve to to proper typescript syntax.

Comment: try with `const errors = ['SIGTERM', 'SIGINT'] as const`

Comment: or `const errors: NodeJS.Signals[] = ["SIGTERM", "SIGINT"];`

Comment: and how can make it better typescript.